# how to speed up compressing folders over a loop

Tags: linux

I would like to find a fast way to compress folders over a loop. I have 1000 folders and each folder has 40000 files (total size of 3 GB).

Here is my code to do this:

```
for f in Simulation*/; do
echo "$f" &&  
test "$(find "$f" -type f | wc -l)" -eq 40000 &&
find -type f | grep -P '\.csv|\.tiff|\.txt' | tar -czf "${f%/}.tar.gz" "${f%/}" &&
rm -rf "$f"
done
```

Here are some details about the code:

- Step 1: find full folders containing 40000 files
- Step 2: find files with some extensions (.csv, .tiff, .txt) in full folders and compress them
- Step 3: remove raw folders that have been compressed

Any idea on how to improve my code will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it works the way you want, you can remove the `find -type f | grep -P '\.csv|\.tiff|\.txt' |` part since it's being ignored. Have you considered parallelizing it?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. If I remove this part, all files will be compressed. I would like only compressed files with some extensions.

Comment: Please double check that it works the way you think. On a normal GNU/Linux setup, the things you are piping in would be ignored.

Comment: Yes, it works correctly (I also checked each code line) but the loop seems too slow.

Comment: Would you do me a favor and remove the `find -type f | grep -P '\.csv|\.tiff|\.txt' |` and try running the script again, even though you know it will no longer work? (`find -type f` will list files from all your 1000 folders and not just your current one, so if it did work the way you assume, wouldn't it package up all 40,000,000 files in every single archive?)